# Options to pass DOM mouse events from child <object> to parent page

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a SPA that uses a widget drag/drop model for users to design their own dashboard by dragging widgets onto a design surface. Widgets are HTML pages with embedded javascript that are added to the parent DOM with  tags.

I have a particular use case where the parent page needs to know the mouse position on the page even if the mouse is over one of the widget objects. However as DOM events are isolated between the widget object DOM and the parent DOM, I think there is no way to easily have the mouse events bubble into the parent DOM (eg. pointer-events won't work), and have started to write a simple event notification system between the widget and the parent page.

Before I go too far with building my own event plumbing, I wanted to check with the stackoverflow community that there is no sneaky way to get the parent to receive the mouse events bubbling from the widget object with built in HTML/CSS/JavaScript functions?

(I would setup a fiddle to show this but I don't think it is possible to simulate an embedded object with a separate HTML page)

```
    // Create widgets
    function loadWidget(myFrag, widgetNum) {
        var widgetObj = document.createElement("object");
        widgetObj.type = "text/html";
        widgetObj.data = "widgets/" + widgets[widgetNum].type + "." + widgets[widgetNum].ext + parent.debugURL                                  // location of widget
        widgetObj.className = "widget";
        widgetObj.id = "widgetObj" + widgetNum;
        widgetObj.addEventListener("load", widgetLoaded, false);
        myFrag.appendChild(widgetObj);                                                                                                          // build widgets onto fragment
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to get the full picture but you should be able to bind events to a parent element and check the `event` `target` (or something like that).. Are all elements within the same document (not using iframes)?

Comment: It sounds like you are using `<embed>`, `<object>`, or `<iframe>` for your widgets. You may want to look into [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send events from the child DOM to the parent

Comment: Yes, using <object> tags dynamically added via javascript. Code snippet added above. parent.postMessage looks like a good way to send generic messages but won't enable mouse event bubbling (although I can code something equivalent). enapupe, how can I bind mouse messages from the object DOM to the parent DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross-origin frames, there is no way to have your gesture events bubble in both framed and main doc.
MouseEvents can't be cloned as is by `postMessage` either, but you could create a simple object yourself with only the props you need from the event.

```
parent.postMessage({
  type: event.type,
  clientX: event.clientX,
  clientY: event.clientY,
  target_id: event.target.id // (elements can't be cloned for postMessage)
}, '*')
```

An other option would be to send a message to the parent so that it activates an overlaying element to capture mouse events at certain moments only, but you'd loose the events in the frame.

But since it appears that your framed documents are from the same origin as your main document, then you can simply add an listener from the main document :

```
// obj is your <object> element
// wait for it to load
  // (may require an obj.data = obj.data for some UA when the page has been cached)
obj.onload = e => { 
  const doc = obj.contentDocument; // get access to the framed Document
  const target = doc.querySelector(selector); // get access to the target
  target.addEventListener(eventType, eventHandler); // yes that's all
  // now eventHandler will be executed from the main doc, with the event from the framed one
 };
```

### [Live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjAVrrYg6B8HvMipRtdG?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for putting the demo together. One point to note - the mouse clientX and Y are relative to the child DOM not the parent DOM, so some adjustment required adding clientX and client from the child to the last clientX, Y of the parent.